# Convert Datetime to date field to pass into Google BigQuery

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I am uploading data into BigQuery Cloud by my c# Application. I have column in BigQuery table 'ForDate' with datatype 'Date'.

But in c# datatype is 'datetime'(As date datatype not supported in c#)
I am getting Below error on uploading data to bigquery:
{Invalid date: '2017-01-02T00:00:00' Field: ForDate; Value: 2017-01-02T00:00:00}

What could be the workaround to upload date with date part only and ignore time part from it?

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me:

```
string currentdatetime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");
```

From:

[How can I format DateTime to web UTC format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820915/how-can-i-format-datetime-to-web-utc-format)

Comment: This is not working for me. I've looked at: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/ and it has a similar solution, BUT if I try to set date to: 'DateTime.UtcNow' its not working neither by ToUniversalTime() or by the StringFormat, any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Import said column as a string, parse in BigQuery to a timestamp value later.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('2017-01-02T00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

The date field in the BigQuery schema should be marked as a TimeStamp not as a DateTime field. Then you can simply insert the row with:

```
bqr.Add(attribute, date.ToUniversalTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while since this question was asked, but for me none of the answers was correct. It seems that the BigQuery NuGet doesn't like date times with specified kind (e.g UTC), and `ToUniversalTime()` produces an UTC kind.

The only trick that worked for me was to create a new instance of DateTime with none (`Unspecified`) kind.

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var dt = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second, now.Millisecond);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
BigQueryDateTimeExtensions.AsBigQueryDate(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

From: [Class BigQueryDateTimeExtensions](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/latest/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryDateTimeExtensions)

For DateTime use:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s")
```