# c# convert DateTimeOffset to zulu time in razor

Tags: c#, razor, datetimeoffset

is there any extension i can use to convert/display my DateTimeOffset type property to Zulu time in razor (cshtml file)?
example:

```
DateTimeOffset = 1028 -----> Zulu = 1428
```

none of the ToString extension can convert to zulu. example below

```
myDate.ToString("t")
```

i like to know if i have to make a converter, or if there's an easier way to do in razor

Comment: [`DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey im assuming there's more to that, because if just that did not convert to zulu

Comment: Well, you have to read the article I linked.  There are some flags you may have to set properly.

Comment: If I understand your question properly it may be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820915/how-can-i-format-datetime-to-web-utc-format

Answer (score -2, accepted):

turns out Zulu time is 4 hours ahead of DateTimeOffSet time. and it is equivalent to UtcDateTime. So all i had to do was

```
myDate.UtcDateTime.Tostring("t")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display something in zulu time, you can do .ToString("u"). This will give you something like this: "2020-02-24 19:17:12Z"