# Date binding dd-mm-yyyy in ASP NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, data-binding

Im trying send date in format `dd/mm/yyyy` as query string parameter but binding for date property not working for me, only if I send date US format  `mm/dd/yyyy` , any idea how to solve?

Comment: Hi @hooliday,any update about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we solve this situation by using `Custom model binding`.

You can see my code example below.

Action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Demo([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))] DateTime MyTime)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

DateTimeModelBinder:

```
 public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("MyTime");

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
       
        var TestTime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(TestTime);
      
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Url:`https://localhost:xxxx/api/xxx/?mytime=19/05/2020`

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to send your date in UTC format. For example:

```
"2020-11-19T10:21:05Z"
```

Then ASP.Net Core will bind it automatically. Using UTC format is also considered a good practice. You easily cast your date object to UTC string using

```cs
string foo = yourDateTime.ToUniversalTime()
                         .ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffK");
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820915/how-can-i-format-datetime-to-web-utc-format)

Or in JavaScript

```js
new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC').toISOString();
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)