# Conversion of a UTC date/time string in C#

Tags: c#, tryparse

I need to convert the string `"Fri Sep 11 00:00:00 GMT+04:00 2020"` into a `DateTime` object `11.09.2011`.

When I use

```
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParseExact(MyString, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
```

`result` is equal to `{9/10/2020 11:00:00 PM}`.

How can I modify the code so that the date component is `11.09.2011` and **not** `10.09.2011` (I only need the date and don't care about the time) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parse into a `DateTimeOffset` instead, given that you've *got* an offset. From the [documentation of the `zz` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzSpecifier) that you're using:

> With DateTime values, the "zz" custom format specifier represents the signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC, measured in hours. It does not reflect the value of an instance's DateTimeKind property. For this reason, the "zz" format specifier is not recommended for use with DateTime values.

So you'd end up with:

```
DateTimeOffset result;
bool success = DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact
         (text, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz yyyy", 
          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
```

From there, you can take the `DateTime` part, which will be midnight on September 11th.

If you want *just* a date, you could use my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project to create a `LocalDate`:

```
LocalDate = OffsetDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(result).LocalDateTime.Date;
```

(I'd love to suggest parsing directly to `OffsetDateTime`, but we haven't got support for that yet. We're hoping to include it in version 1.2.)

Answer (score 4):

C# does not have a pure `Date` type.
If you don't care about the time, just ignore that portion of the `DateTime`.

If you want the time to always be midnight, use the `.Date` property, which will return a `DateTime` with the same date but at midnight.

Comment: The problem is that I get `10.09.2011` (wrong) instead of `11.09.2011` (correct). I. e. I need a hint on how to modify the code such that `result` is equal to `11.09.2011 ...` (where ... is the time, which is irrelevant for me).