# How to parse custom string to DateTime C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to parse to following Date `Aug 20 11:38:43 2017 GMT`
I'm trying to use  `DateTime.TryParseExact` but can't find the correct format.

my latest format is  `MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy`

my code :

```
string nextUpdate; //Next Update: Aug 20 11:38:43 2017 GMT
string dateTimeFormat =          "MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy";
DateTime crldt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(nextUpdate.Split(':')[1].Trim(), dateTimeFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out crldt);
```

when I run the code I get crldt ~ Date = {1/1/01 12:00:00 AM}

my question : what format should I use or what alternative way can I use to parse this string to DateTime

**UPDATE**

using suggestions from : @Sergey Berezovskiy
I've updated the code to :

```
    string nextUpdate; //  Next Update: Oct  7 06:16:18 2017 GMT
    string dateTimeFormat = @"MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy \G\M\T";
    Regex r =new Regex(".*Next Update:.*");
    nextUpdate = r.Match(Crltext).Value;
    DateTime crldt;             


  DateTime.TryParseExact(nextUpdate.Substring(nextUpdate.IndexOf(':')+1).Trim(),
  dateTimeFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
  System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out crldt);
  int intDTComp = DateTime.Compare(crldt, DT_now);
```

I've found a date that doesn't fit this format :   `Next Update: Oct  7 06:16:18 2017 GMT`
what is the issue now ?

**UPDATE 2**

I've found the issue , but can't find a clean solution. 
The issue is that the problematic date is `Oct 7 ...` , 
while the format is `MMM dd ...`

my workaround is adding another format `MMM d hh:mm:ss yyyy` and using it if `date = {1/1/01 12:00:00 AM}`

what other solution may I use in this scenario

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105457/string-to-utc-time-conversion

Comment: Why are you using `Split()`?  Isn't that just passing `"38"` to be parsed?  `"38"` isn't a date.  Or is it passing `"Aug 20 11"`?  Also not a date.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't forget that your string contains `"GMT"`. You should either remove it from the string, or add to format pattern:

```
string nextUpdate = "Next Update: Aug 20 11:38:43 2017 GMT";
string format = @"MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy \G\M\T";
```

Next - don't split input string by `:` because there is another `:` symbols in the string. And you will get array with parts `["Next Update", " Aug 20 11", "38", "43 2017 GMT"]`. Taking the second item from array gives you `" Aug 20 11"`. Instead, you should just take substring after first `:` occurance:

```
string s = nextUpdate.Substring(nextUpdate.IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
```

And finally parse that string using your format:

```
IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Output will depend on your time zone. E.g. for my time zone GMT+3 it will be:

```
8/20/2017 14:38:43
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your string:

```
"Next Update: Aug 20 11:38:43 2017 GMT"
```

Then when you do this:

```
nextUpdate.Split(':')[1].Trim()
```

You get this:

```
"Aug 20 11"
```

Which doesn't match your date format.  I suspect you don't just want the second split value, but also all remaining split values.  You can re-join them.  Something like this:

```
string.Join(":", nextUpdate.Split(':').Skip(1)).Trim()
```

This would split them by the `":"` character, skip the first one but keep all remaining ones, and re-join the remaining ones into another string with the `":"` character again.

Note: You may also need to account for that time zone value.  There are some helpful ideas [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-time-zone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc) for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the input, I propose that you take the format exactly as the input

```
string nextUpdate = "Next Update: Aug 20 11:38:43 2017 GMT";
string dateTimeFormat = @"\N\e\x\t\ \U\p\d\a\t\e\:\ MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy\ \G\M\T";
DateTime crldt;
crldt = DateTime.ParseExact(nextUpdate, dateTimeFormat , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

This way, when reading the code it's very clear what the expected format is, and you don't have code with `Split()` or other items that need explanation.

Also note that if you leave the colons (`:`) like that, they may be replaced by .NET to match the hour separator. Use `\:` if you always require a literal colon.

As I wrote in the comments before, note that you're [ignoring the time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241789/480982).

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime givenDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Aug 20 14:38:43 2017 GMT", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy GMT", provider); // here HH is for 24 hour format . use hh for 12 hour format
string expectedDate = givenDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt");  // tt is for AM or PM (no need to use tt if you use hour as HH I mean 24 hour format)
```

Your Output will be `20/08/17 11:38:43 AM`