# Why doesn't DateTime.ToLocalTime() take into account daylight savings?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a a UTC time string (that I get from a database, so I can't change the format) that is created with `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s")`. I would like to display something user-facing like "10:00 AM". Where I am (in England), the clocks have recently gone forward and the following method is an hour out:

```
var timenowstring = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s");
var dateutc = DateTime.Parse(timenowstring).ToShortTimeString();
var datelocal = DateTime.Parse(timenowstring).ToLocalTime().ToShortTimeString();

Console.WriteLine("Utc time string: " + dateutc);
Console.WriteLine("Local time string: " + datelocal);
```

Both print "9:02 AM" when actually it's 10:02 AM.

Here's a screenshot of it repro-ing on http://csharppad.com/ :

[image: utc and local show the same time - see system clock in lower right, which is correct]
[bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Vq0.png)

[CSharpPad gist](http://csharppad.com/gist/d56dee34ab9e3d0b1a17)

What am I doing wrong and what's the easiest way to get a DateTime object which will return the right time when I call `.ToShortTimeString()`?

NB [the docs on ToLocalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say:

> The conversion also takes into account the daylight saving time rule that applies to the time represented by the current DateTime object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't DateTime.Parse parse UTC date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756639/why-cant-datetime-parse-parse-utc-date)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said:

> I have a a UTC time string (that I get from a database, so I can't change the format) that is created with `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s")`.

Right off the bat, you have a problem.  Dates in a database are (usually) not stored as strings.  They're stored in fields with a specific data type.  In SQL Server (for example) you may be using a `datetime` or `datetime2` field.  These are not strings.  When you retrieve them into your .NET code, they are converted directly to a `DateTime` type.  If you are treating it as a string, you are doing it wrong.

For example, your data access code might be doing something like this:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["myDateTimeField"].ToString());
```

That is very common, and completely wrong.  You should instead be doing this:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) dataReader["myDateTimeField"];
```

Or if the field is nullable:

```
DateTime? dt = dataReader["myDateTimeField"] as DateTime;
```

Once you load the value properly instead of parsing it as a string, the rest will work out fine.  The `DateTime` value will have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` for its `Kind` property, and when you call `ToLocalTime` on it, it will assume that you wanted to treat the unspecified value as UTC.  ([See the chart on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx).)

Regarding the code you posted, while it's a bit messy (going through strings unnecessarily), it would actually work just fine - assuming you ran it in *your* time zone.  In the `ToLocalTime` method, "local" means the local time zone setting of the machine wherever the code happens to be running.  **For csharppad.com, the time zone happens to be UTC**.  It has no way of knowing you want to use England's time zone rules.

[image: CSharpPad Time Zone]

If you intend to run your code on a server, then you shouldn't be using `ToLocalTime` at all - as the time zone of the server is likely to be irrelevant.  Instead, you could use `TimeZoneInfo` to convert the time:

```
// this uses the time zone for England
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
DateTime englandDatetime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, tz);
```

Alternatively, you could use the open-source [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, like this:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
DateTime englandDateTime = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utcDateTime)
                                  .InZone(tz)
                                  .ToDateTimeUnspecified();
```

Comment: I’d argue that `dataReader["myDateTimeField"] as DateTime` is a bit unsafe. You *want* an exception thrown if the value of the field turns out not to be `NULL`. You’d rather `var ordinal = dataReader.GetOrdinal("myDateTimeField"); var dt = dataReader.IsDbNull(ordinal) ? new DateTime?() : dataReader.GetDateTime(ordinal);`. That way, if the library has a way to not do a runtime dynamic cast, it will avoid that, and if it isn’t a `DateTime` or `NULL`, you will get an exception pointing out an issue that might be a bug and save yourself the hassle of hunting down strange issues later.

Answer (score 1):

For others who think DateTime.ToLocalTime is ignoring Daylight Savings time (like I did), something to realize is that the Date you are converting is the basis for whether or not Daylight Savings time is considered.

Example: Converting a UTC DateTime of '1/1/2020' to my local (Central US), I get: '12/31/2019 18:00:00', which is correct. As I was running this in April and Daylight Savings is in effect, I was expecting UTC-5:00 instead of UTC-6:00. But January is CST,not CDT, so UTC-6:00 was correct.

Your problem could be 'user error' as it was mine.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code locally, it gives expected results (local time corresponds to my machine local time).
Although when I run it on http://csharppad.com, times are same. Reason is mentioned in Matt Johnson's answer: Servers have different time zones from local machines.