# DateTime.ToLocalTime not working properly with daylight savings

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have a `DateTime` instance with `Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc` and a timespan.

```
var dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
var ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
```

When I localize `dt` and then add `ts` I get a different result than when I add `ts` and then localize, due to daylight savings.

```
var localizedFirst = dt.ToLocalTime() + ts; //Does account for daylight savings
var addedFirst = (dt + ts).ToLocalTime(); //Does not account for daylight savings
```

This seems very strange.  Shouldn't adding an offset from localization and adding an offset from a timespan be commutative and associative?

I found a similar question: [Why doesn't DateTime.ToLocalTime() take into account daylight savings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557418/why-doesnt-datetime-tolocaltime-take-into-account-daylight-savings) That question is dealing more with converting `DateTime` to and from `String`.  I am working only with `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` arithmetic.

The best answer for that question suggested using `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` so that the runtime will assume the unspecified date is UTC and then it will convert it properly when localizing.  I was very surprised that this actually worked.  If I create a new `DateTime` like this:

```
var dt2 = new DateTime(dt.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Then both orders of operations return the correct result with daylight savings.

```
(dt2 + ts).ToLocalTime() 
dt2.ToLocalTime() + ts
```

This all seems absurd to me.  Why do I need to convert a `Utc` date to `Unspecified` just to convert it to `Local` properly?  This seems like it should be considered a bug.

Other details:

- Framework: .NET 4.6.1
- My local timezone: Eastern Standard Time (USA)
- An actual value being used by `dt`: `11/5/2017 2:36:13pm UTC`
- An actual value being used by `ts`: `TimeSpan.FromDays(699)`
- Local equivalent of `dt`: `11/5/2017 9:36:13am`
- Value of `(dt + ts).ToLocalTime()`: `10/5/2019 10:36:13am`
- Value of `dt.ToLocalTime() + ts`: `10/5/2019 9:36:13am`

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?  The 2.0/3.5 runtime handles Dates differently than the 4.x runtime.  A few years ago I ran into a LOT of discrepancies.  They may have been resolved since then, but either way, framework version would be helpful.

Comment: maybe this article will help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx

Comment: Can you provide specific times and timezone (what timezone, what time is dt, when daylight savings take effect in that zone)? Because it's important for this kind of questions. But in general - arithmetic operations on date time (like adding days - your case) do not take daylight savings into account, while conversion operations (like ToLocalTime - also your case) do.

Comment: It is the time of the year again.  What happens is entirely normal, (dt + ts) is still utc so can be properly be adjusted for dst.  But local time + ts stays local time.  And cannot be adjusted because local time is ambiguous.

Comment: Another important question here:  do you happen to be in Arizona or Hawaii (states that do not adjust for DST)?

Comment: @HansPassant But shouldn't adding an offset to a local time offset it by a fixed amount from the starting localized date?

Comment: @SteveDanner I get a discrepancy (in UK local timezone) just by deducting 20 days rather than adding 1 day. This takes us back into daylight savings. I believe it's working as intended. How else could we change the date without changing the time? And how else could we find out the local time exactly 480 hours ago?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I agree...since UTC is NEVER DST and local times are.  I'm finding that if the target is within DST, it's off.  But if we're on Std time, its' not.  Makes sense now.  I'll delete previous comments.

Answer (score 5):

A few points:

- A `TimeSpan` represents an elapsed duration of time.  Its "days" are *standard days* that are exactly 24 hours long.
- On the day in question, in the local time zone, there were 25 hours because of the DST fall-back transition.
- Addition on a `DateTime` object (either by `+` operator or `Add...` functions) is always done without regard for time zone.  In other words, whatever the original `.Kind` property is, the output will have the same `.Kind` property, but the kind is not taken into consideration at all during addition/subtraction.
- Thus, adding *after* converting to local time does not account for the 25 hour day.  It is also problematic because it's possible to land on a local time value that does not exist, or exists twice.

So, when you say "does (or does not) account for daylight saving" in the code comments, technically you have it reversed.  Since UTC has no transitions, the `localizedFirst` variable is the result of incorrectly assuming the local day is 24 hours long, while the `addedFirst` variable is the result of correctly applying the DST rules from the local time zone at the point that is 24 hours elapsed after the original point on the timeline.

Also, setting `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` will not change the effect for this case, because the `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` method will treat `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` as if it were `DateTimeKind.Utc`.  [See the table in the remarks of the documentation here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netframework-4.6.1#Remarks)  Indeed, I tried to replicate your results and could not get the value of `dt2` to be any different just by changing the kind.  If you can, please elaborate specifically on that point.

It's worth pointing out that eliminating this sort of confusion is exactly why the [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) library exists.  In Noda Time, these are represented by two very different operations:

- `LocalDateTime + Period = LocalDateTime`
- `Instant + Duration = Instant`

Comment: If this was a greenfield project I would definitely be using NodaTime, but its a tough dependency to change after 10 years.

Comment: @JamesFaix so you can provide reproducable example of how date kind unspecified helps or that was some mistake at your side?

Comment: @Evk I was using a DateTime of `11/5/2017 2:36:13pm UTC` and adding `TimeSpan.FromDays(699)`.  If I created an unspecified DateTime from that one, by copying its Ticks value, the operations because commutative, but if I stuck with the UTC original they were not.

Answer (score 4):

This statement effectively asks for the day to be advanced but all other properties (hour, minute of day) to be left intact:

```
var localizedFirst = dt.ToLocalTime() + ts;
```

Whilst this statement asks what the local time will be after exactly 24 hours (elapsed time) have passed:

```
var addedFirst = (dt + ts).ToLocalTime();
```

It's a good argument for keeping everything in UTC until the last minute, then converting to Local Time for output.

**Edit**: Or conversely, if you don't want the local hours and minutes to change when you add or deduct days, convert to local time before adding the `TimeSpan`. **However**, as rightly pointed out by Matt Johnson, in this way you might end up with a local time that is either invalid (the clocks went forward over that time) or ambiguous (the clocks went back, so that time occurred twice). See his comment below for how to determine this.

Comment: Yes, this is true, except that the result of `localizedFirst` may possibly be invalid or ambiguous.  The `IsInvalidTime` and `IsAmbiguousTime` methods from `TimeZoneInfo` will tell you if they are or not, and then you can adjust accordingly if necessary.  Ultimately, such "add calendar days with respect to a time zone" should probably be built in to the framework, but presently it is not.