# Trouble parsing (almost) RoundtripKind date in C#

Tags: c#, date, parsing, datetime, date-parsing

I'm consuming a Java client which returns me a Date like `2016-09-02T16:18:54.000 UTC`. Notice the ending, which is not exactly standard format.

If I trim the "UTC" I can successfully parse the date:

```
DateTime.Parse("2016-09-02T16:18:54.000")
```

but the result's Kind is Unspecified, instead of UTC (obviously); I can bypass that by replacing "UTC" with "Z" like so:

```
DateTime.Parse("2016-09-02T16:18:54.000Z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind)
```

However ideally I'd like not to mess with the input.

Took a couple of stabs at this with TryParseExact and different formats but failed with each one:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2016-09-02T16:18:54.000 UTC", new [] {
 "o",
 "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff UTC",
 "yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss:fff UTC",
 "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:fff UTC"
}, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out startDate)
```

I'm pretty sure the "UTC" keyword is not the issue (since [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756697/1791065) have successfully used it), but rather that "T" that I can't seem to know how to parse: not even the "o" format that I think was implicitly used in my second code snippet seems to work:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2016-09-02T16:18:54.000Z", "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out startDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is like `2016-09-02T16:18:54.000 UTC`,this works for me:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2016-09-02T16:18:54.000 UTC", 
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff UTC"
, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out startDate);
```

Comment: @CodeCaster according to OP question, his input is `2016-09-02T16:18:54.000 UTC`?

Comment: the space before the UTC is not the issue, using HH instead of hh fixed it, thanks a mill!

Comment: @Pikoh played with the DateTimeStyles, didn't manage to get the DateTimeKind that I wanted (Utc), had to explicitly use SpecifyKind instead