# Problem converting date time string to proper date time value

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core

I am receiving a datetime string from an API that I am attempting to convert into a DateTime variable, but when I do the converse it keeps giving me the wrong time.

Here's one of the values I am getting from the api:

```
2020-04-21T21:44:34Z
```

I'm trying to bring this back as 4/21/2020 9:44:34 PM but it keeps giving me 4/21/2020 4:44:34 PM instead. (The minutes, seconds, and dates are correct.)

I've tried...

```
DateTime startTimeStr = Convert.ToDateTime("2020-04-21T21:44:34Z")
```

... and

```
DateTime startTimeStr = DateTime.Parse("2020-04-21T21:44:34Z");
```

Both give me the 4 PM time not 9 PM.

Comment: @David What timezone do you live in?

Comment: Did the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756699/34092 help (i.e. `AdjustToUniversal`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `.ToUniversalTime()` on your parse result:

```
DateTime startTimeStr = DateTime.Parse("2020-04-21T21:44:34Z").ToUniversalTime();
```

Or specifying `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` on corresponding [`Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_) overload:

```
DateTime startTimeStr = DateTime.Parse("2020-04-21T21:44:34Z", null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Without that `DateTime.Parse` parses `DateTime` and adjusts it to your local timezone (checking `DateTime.Kind` property will give you `DateTimeKind.Local`).

Comment: Yep. That did it. Thanks!