# convert string with utc-datetime to datetime-Ojbect

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, utc

First of all I am new in C#.

I have to convert a `string` like

```
  "Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC)"
```

into a `DateTime`. I've tried serveral *format strings* (like `"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"`, `"r"`, `"R"`). But I always get the **error message**

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Here is my last code for this:

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string timeStampFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTime myDateTime;

myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
  stringToFormat, 
  timeStampFormat, 
  enUS, 
  DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Thanks for your support.

Best regards
Andreas## Heading ##

Comment: Seems to be similar/partial dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756639/why-cant-datetime-parse-parse-utc-date.  Replace " (UTC)" with "Z" and try again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse DateTime with time zone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-time-zone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can have not only `(UTC)`, but `(UTC+4)`, `(UTC-5)` and alike suffixes, I suggest *escaping* `(UTC` and `)`:

```
  string stringToFormat = "Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC)";

  ...

  DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    stringToFormat, 
    new string[] { 
      "ddd, d MMM yyyy H:m:s '(UTC)'",
      "ddd, d MMM yyyy H:m:s '(UTC'z')'",
    },
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

**Demo:**

```
  DateTime demo(string text) => DateTime.ParseExact(
    text, 
    new string[] { 
      "ddd, d MMM yyyy H:m:s '(UTC)'",
      "ddd, d MMM yyyy H:m:s '(UTC'z')'",
    },
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);

  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC)",
    "Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC-1)",
    "Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC+1)",
    "Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC-14)",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-40} => {demo(test):dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC)          => 30.07.2021 11:57:58
Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC-1)        => 30.07.2021 12:57:58
Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC+1)        => 30.07.2021 10:57:58
Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC-14)       => 31.07.2021 01:57:58
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the `(UTC)` which is causing the string to not be recognized as a timestamp. You could account for the `(UTC)` by removing it, I have provided one method to accomplish this here.

```
        string stringToFormat = "Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC)";

        string[] SubString = stringToFormat.Split('(');
        stringToFormat = SubString[0].Trim();

        string timeStampFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        DateTime mydateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringToFormat, timeStampFormat, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Or replace the `(UTC)` with the offset from UTC, which in this case would be 0, and add `(z)` to timeStampFormat.

```
        string stringToFormat = "Fri, 30 Jul 2021 11:57:58 (UTC)";
        stringToFormat = stringToFormat.Replace("(UTC)", "(-0)");

        string timeStampFormat = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss (z)";
        DateTime mydateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringToFormat, timeStampFormat, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings