# How to parse text with UTC from IWebElement into date. Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, date-parsing

I've got one problem. I can't parse text from IWebElement into dateTime with UTC.

Selenium without any problem takes text from page:

> 14.02.2022 09:46:12 UTC

And path to element is correct :

```
 string dateOfAction = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//div[1]//span[1]")).Text;
```

I would like to parse this string from `dateOfAction`(with this same UTC format) into date.

```
 var actionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfAction, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ssZ", null).ToUniversalTime();
```

if try get `string dateOfAction`I have `"14/02/2022 09:46:12 UTC"`. But if I trying do

`var actionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfAction, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ssZ", null).ToUniversalTime();` or just try
`var actionDate = DateTime.Parse(dateOfAction);` the result is not as I expect `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`

How to correctly parse string dateOfAction to DateTime dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss with UTC like in span above?

Comment: Try : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC"

Comment: Shouldn't the format end with `HH:mm:ss Z` (a space after the "ss" and before the "Z")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers!

I've solved problem using

Date from web page:

> 14.02.2022 09:46:12 UTC

So I've got string from span, and parsed into date like bellow.

```
string dateOfAction = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//div[{actionCounter}]//span[1]")).Text;                            
var actionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateOfAction, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC", null).ToUniversalTime();
```

Variable `actionDate` has value `14.02.2022 09:46:12 UTC.`

and it is good solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I see you direct issue is solved but please cf. to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756639/why-cant-datetime-parse-parse-utc-date) for more information.